# How to download a excel file from sharepoint using powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to download excel file from sharepoint using powershell. I am trying below code but unfortunately its not working.

```
$fromfile = "https://test.sharepoint.com/test.xlsx"

$tofile   = "c:\Script\new.xlsx"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

$webclient.DownloadFile($fromfile, $tofile)
```

Thanks

Comment: Running above code throwing below error:

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

At line:12 char:1

+ $webclient.DownloadFile($fromfile, $tofile)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Comment: Are you sure that URL is correct? Typically it should look like this: https://company.sharepoint.com/siteName/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/sites/siteName/Shared%20Documents/spreadsheet.xlsx

Comment: Also, (403) Forbidden sounds like creds are not working. Maybe try Invoke-Webrequest -usedefaultcredentials

Answer (score 0):

Some servers require the `User-Agent` header. Add this before your last line:

```
$webclient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
```